# Transaction sent from web3 cannot reached all transaction to network node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, dapps

I used one node endpoint to interact with the network. While sending a transaction from web3.js 0.20 to ethereum network, transaction per second (TPS) I achieved is only 28 TPS. I have configured the network in such a way to handle 100 TPS by increasing block Gas limit. whereas I achieved-

> Above 30 tps transaction sent from web3js cannot actually be sent all transaction 
>   to node properly.  I am sure that, this is not due to Block Time and
>   Block Gas Limit.

Why web3js is not sending all transaction to the network node in higher TPS. Is there anything that restricts to send transaction in higher TPS ?